# Unable to Login when passing credentials in a web url

Tags: php, mysql

Creating a `user login`, when I use `username` and `password` within PHP file then, I am getting **Done** as user `exists`. Which is `GOOD`

```
<?php

    .....

    /*** for sample */
    // $_POST["username"] = "sun";
    // $_POST["password"] = "live";

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $strSQL = "select * from test_users where username = '".$username."' and  password = '".$password."' ";

    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumRows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);

    if($intNumRows==0)
    {
    echo "Not Done" ;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Done" ;
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

But, when I pass these values in web url, I am always getting, Not Done as message. WHY

```
 http://mydomain.info/retrofit_user/login.php?username=sun&&password=live
```

Comment: in the url they are GET not POST

Comment: SQL Injection at its best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ampersands in your query strings, that's an issue.

```
login.php?username=sun&&password=live
```

Not to mention that POST and GET are different method.

You can use `$_REQUEST` two access both.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your variables in PHP as `$_POST`.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

But in your link, it's the `$_GET` method.

```
login.php?username=sun&password=live
```

So, it should be:

Also, remember to prevent MySQL Injection, using `mysql_escape_string()`.

```
$username = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_GET['password']);
```

**Please use `MySQLi` instead as `MySQL` has already been deprecated.**

Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this for more read  http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

```
$username = $_GET['username'] ?? $_POST['username'] ?? 'sun';
$password = $_GET['password'] ?? $_POST['password'] ?? 'live';
```